# Google Sheets' IMPORTXML breaks randomly

Tags: google-sheets, hosting, web-hosting, google-sheets-formula

I'm writing since I'm experiencing some issues with the following `IMPORTXML` formula in Google Sheets:

```
=IMPORTXML("http://xmltestmagicplan.000webhostapp.com/xml_test.xml","/catalog/book[2]")
```

The formula works fine most of the times but approximately once a day it breaks, showing an error in loading the formula and giving `#N/A` as a result.

The workaround is changing anything in the URL (i.e. `http` -> `https` or `000webhostapp.com` -> `000webhostapp.org`) and then changing it back. Basically I think the workaround is forcing Google Sheets to reload the formula.

The same thing happens if I use this formula:

```
=IMPORTXML("http://xmltestmagicplan.000webhostapp.com/xml_test.xml")
```

No problem instead with the following formulas:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Ram-N/5189462/raw/46db0b43ad7bf9cbd32a8932f3ab981bd4b4da7c/books.xml","/catalog/book[2]")
```

---

```
=IMPORTXML("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Ram-N/5189462/raw/46db0b43ad7bf9cbd32a8932f3ab981bd4b4da7c/books.xml")
```

I think the issue is due to the hosting (000webhostapp.com) I'm using but I can't figure why. Any ideas?

Comment: I've had similar problems with `=importrange()` and `=indirect()`. Makes it difficult to rely on those functions.

Comment: @a-burge, I tried with the workaround player0 suggested and it seems it works at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to trick it like this:

```
=IFERROR(
 IMPORTXML("http://xmltestmagicplan.000webhostapp.com/xml_test.xml", "/catalog/book[2]"), 
 IMPORTXML("http://xmltestmagicplan.000webhostapp.com/xml_test.xml", "/catalog/book[2]"))
```

or if the switch is too fast add 1 fake switch between like:

```
=IFERROR(IFERROR(
 IMPORTXML("http://xmltestmagicplan.000webhostapp.com/xml_test.xml", "/catalog/book[2]"), 
 IMPORTXML("http://xmltestmagicplan.000webhostapp.ORG/xml_test.xml", "/catalog/book[2]")),
 IMPORTXML("http://xmltestmagicplan.000webhostapp.com/xml_test.xml", "/catalog/book[2]"))
```

Comment: Thanks, it sounds like a good idea. I'll give it a try and I'll let you know.

Comment: Sadly, this did not work for me. It breaks the same, as without IFERROR, even when it's doubled.

Comment: But the solution adding a cell with =Minute(Now)) somewhere and concatenating its cell to the URL via &"&"A1 works for me. But sometimes with the cell only in another sheet.